# Rails Data Modeling to Connect Multiple Models

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a data modeling question. My User model belongs_to an Appointment model. The Appointment model has_many users. Users can add Appointments. When doing so each Appointment gets a user_id.

Now I want to let Administrators add Appointments for Users, but the association automatically fills in the user_id with the current_user (the Administrator). How do I pass the user_id of the User to the Appointment model when Administrators are adding Appointments? I want Users or Administrators to be able to modify their Appointments later on. I would like the user_id to be able available for searching. I'm using CanCan for authorization.

**Question:** 
Should this be done with a polymorphic association, or is there a simpler way? If this question has been answered, please post a link.

For reference the User model is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :appointments
belongs_to :administrator
```

The Appointment model:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

The Administrator model:

```
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users
```

I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2.0.

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue a while back, but just cleaning this up. Turns out I had a simple_form issue. I wasn't using value_method to pass the user_id correctly. All is working now.